# Opening Local Notification Opens to Specific View

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uilocalnotification

When user clicks the notification, I want the app to open up to the third tab on my tab bar controller.  I can get the notification to fire, but not the opening up right part.  In my app's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions I have:

```
 UILocalNotification *localNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    if (localNotif) {
        tabBarController.selectedIndex = 3;
    }
```

And then in AppDelegate as well, I have:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    NSString *reminderText = [notification.userInfo
                              objectForKey:kRemindMeNotificationDataKey];
    [viewController showReminder:reminderText];
    tabBarController.selectedIndex = 3;
}
```

However, clicking the notification just opens it up, like normal, to the first tab.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20608696/open-specific-tab-bar-when-receive-push-notification).  And also the third tab would be `tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2` since the count starts from 0.