# Open specific tab bar when receive push notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, push-notification, tabbar

How can i open specific tab bar when receive push notification?

i already put `[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];`on viewDidAppear and what happen is in data logging, it showing that it passing through tabBar 2  viewController but it not open/showing that page and remain at the firstView controller/ first tabBar.

and then after i terminate the app and open back, automatically/ suddenly it open the tabBar 2 viewController.

can anyone give any idea or sample code to solve this?

this is in my didReceiveRemoteNotification;

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    NSLog(@"Remote notification received");

    if([userInfo valueForKey:@"app"]) {

        NSString *action_app = [userInfo valueForKey:@"app"];
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setObject:action_app forKey:@"app"];

        NewVC *sample=[[NewVC alloc]init];
        [sample viewDidLoad];

        //[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];

        [self clearNotifications];

    }else{

        NSLog(@"---nothing to read---");
    }
}
```

NewVC are located at tabbar 2.

Comment: write `setSelectedIndex` on didReceiveRemoteNotification method of appDelegate in stead viewDidAppear.

Comment: @Viruss mca..i already done that but nothing happen

Comment: Show what you have done?

Comment: @Viruss mca..i already put the code in question above..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to change tabbar selectedIndex like,

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application  didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    if([userInfo valueForKey:@"app"]) {

      NSString *action_app = [userInfo valueForKey:@"app"];
      NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     [defaults setObject:action_app forKey:@"app"];

   UITabBarController *tabb = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
   tabb.selectedIndex = 2;
 }
}
```

Comment: one more question, this will work if the apps is active. but, when the apps is inactive or terminate, it will only open the main page/tab and not open the tab 2..how can i open tab 2 when receive notification even the apps is inactive or terminate?i already put that code into 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions' but it didn't work.

Comment: bro if app is inactive when you tap on notification from notification center it will call this method.

Comment: yup, i already put that code into this method but it still not work

Comment: Tried to ages to get this to work but just couldn't find the right way of doing it. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @DilipTiwari: You can explain your problem in different Thread.

Comment: i tried above code but it didnot working @ToseefKhilji

Comment: i want to move 3 index of tabbar when click on push  notifications swift 3

Answer (score 3):

### **For Swift**

This is the Push notification data:

```
{

  "aps": {
    "alert" : "Hello Your Order ID 107922341457c134962d002 is Ready. Thank you For choosing us!!",
    "badge" : "1",
    "sound" :"default"
     },

  "order": {
    "item_name" : "Spanish Masala",
    "order_id":"107922341457c134962d002" ,
    "food_id":"15"
    }
}
```

**Here is the code** in `AppDelegate.swift`

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    if loginFlag{
    if let temp = userInfo["order"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
        sharedObject.orderDetailsFromPushNotification = temp
        if let navController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController{
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            if let myViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tabHome") as? MyTabViewController{

                myViewController.selectedIndex = 1

                navController.pushViewController(myViewController, animated: true)


            }}
        }}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here how I do it:

```
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let tabBarVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: StoryboardIDKeys.tabBarViewController.rawValue) as? TabBarViewController //{
        tabBarVC?.selectedIndex = 1
        self.window?.rootViewController = tabBarVC
```